# How to convert string of hex to insert into binary file in C

Tags: c, file, binary, hex

I need to take in some input that is a string and turn it into its equal hex number and put it in place in a binary file.

```
        char *fpath = argv[3];
        FILE *f = fopen(fpath, "wb+");
        char buf[1000];
        char *input = "46AB";

        unsigned int value = strtol(input , NULL, 16);
        sprintf(buf, "\\x%x", value);
        fseek(f, 2, SEEK_SET);
        fputs(buf, f);
```

In the file it produces

```
5C 78 34 36 61
```

while i need it look like

```
46 AB
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: You'll want to use `fwrite` to write the data in `value` directly to the file.

Comment: `snprintf` and `fputs` are string/text operators. You cannot use that to produce binary data. All you need is `fwrite(&value, sizeof(value), 1, f)`

Comment: I believe both these comments are wrong for common little-endian machines.

Comment: If you want see the data as hex values you can check [hex edit](https://hexed.it/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sprintf` call created the string

```
\x46ab
```

and you wrote those six characters to the file without further interpretation, so that's what you saw in the file (hex bytes `5c 78 34 36 61 62`).

To get the hex-to-binary conversion you want, while avoiding byte order issues and anticipating the possibility of an arbitrary-length `input` string, you can do this one byte at a time with code like this:

```
char *p;
for(p = input; *p != '\0'; p += 2) {
    unsigned int x;
    if(sscanf(p, "%2x", &x) != 1) break;
    putc(x, f);
}
```

This uses `sscanf` to convert the `input` string to hexadecimal, two characters (two hexadecimal digits, or one output byte) at a time.

I also tested it with a longer input string:

```
input = "0102034a4b4c";
```

This is quick-and-dirty, imperfect code.  It will misbehave if `input` contains an odd number of characters, and it doesn't deal particularly gracefully with non-hexadecimal characters, either.

An improvement is to use the mildly obscure `%n` format specifier to `scanf` to discover exactly how many characters it consumed each time:

```
for(p = input; *p != '\0'; ) {
    unsigned int x;
    int n;
    if(sscanf(p, "%2x%n", &x, &n) != 1) break;
    putc(x, f);
    p += n;
}
```

This should be more robust against malformed `input` strings, although I have not tested it exhaustively.  (I hardly ever use functions in the scanf family, let alone the more obscure format specifiers like `%n`, but this is one of the few problems I know of where it's attractive, the alternatives being considerably more cumbersome.)

P.S. I got rid of your `fseek` call, because I wasn't sure what it was there for and it confused my testing.  You can put it back in if you need it.